# No rational solutions of a system of equations

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, diophantine-equations

> Please show that there does not exist $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{Q}^3$ such that
>   \begin{matrix}
> a^2b+2b^2c+2ac^2=0\\
> a^2c+ab^2+2bc^2=0\\
> a^3+2b^3+4c^3+12abc=3.
> \end{matrix}

I'm able to show that this is true iff $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt[3]3):\mathbb{Q}]=9$.

Comment: What is the source of the equations?

Comment: And what is your argument that uses the assumption that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=9$ (which is true)?

Comment: It follows by writing $\sqrt[3]3$ as a linear combination of $\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt[3]4,1$ and cubing and equating the coefficients for the basis. I came up with the equations myself.

Comment: I don't know how to show the degree extension is 9 (though intuitive)

Comment: right; thanks; typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prove that there is no $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{Q}^3$ satisfying the three equations, assume that one of $a,b,c$ is non-zero. Let's say that $a\neq 0$. Set $x=b/a$ and $y=c/a$ and divide the first two equations by $a^3$. Then we get $x+2x^2y+2y^2=0$ and $y+x^2+2xy^2=0$. Multiply the first equation by $x$ and substract from the second gives us that $2x^3y=y$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $y(2x^3-1)=0$. Since $x\in\mathbb Q$ we can not have $2x^3-1=0$, so $y=0$. It follows that $c=0$, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add about why $|\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}|=9$, there are at least a couple of ways to go about approaching it.

**Showing that a basis consists of $9$ elements.**

You can make an intuitive guess about what a possible basis would be. Starting with $1,\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt[3]{2}^2,\sqrt[3]{3}^2$, a guess for the other $4$ basis elements would be $\sqrt[3]{2}\sqrt[3]{3}=\sqrt[3]{6}$, $\sqrt[3]{2}\sqrt[3]{3}^2$, $\sqrt[3]{2}^2\sqrt[3]{3}$, and $\sqrt[3]{2}^2\sqrt[3]{3}^2=\sqrt[3]{6}^2$. It's then just a case of showing that these are linearly independent and spanning.

**Showing that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, where the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has degree $9$.**

You might be familiar with the fact that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$. In this case, it also happens that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{3})$, with minimal polynomial $x^9-15x^6-87x^3-125$.

Comment: Hi Warren Moore. How would you show the 9 elements are linearly independent?

Comment: Well $1,\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{2}^2$ certainly are because they form a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$. You should be able to show that no $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of these will give you $\sqrt[3]{3}$ (otherwise $\sqrt[3]{3}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$). You can keep adding elements to your list, because you won't be able to write any of them as a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of the ones before it.

Comment: Is it true in general that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]p,\sqrt[n]q)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]p+\sqrt[n]q)$ for primes $p,q$? Thanks.

Comment: It suffices to find $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\zeta_n^i\sqrt[n]{p}+x\zeta_n^j\sqrt[n]{q}\ne\sqrt[n]{p}+x\sqrt[n]{q}$, for $i=0,\dots,n-1$, $j=1,\dots,n-1$. Then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{p},\sqrt[n]{q})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{p}+x\sqrt[n]{q})$. So in your case, you're asking if $x=1$ will always work. If $n$ is odd, then this is true, since $\sqrt[n]{p}+\sqrt[n]{q}\in\mathbb{R}$, but $\zeta_n^i\sqrt[n]{p}+\zeta_n^j\sqrt[n]{q}\notin\mathbb{R}$, for $i=0,\dots,n-1$, $j=1,\dots,n-1$. What can you conclude if $n$ is even?

Comment: No $\mathbb Q$-linear combination of $1,\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt[3]4$ gives $\sqrt[3]3$ is basically equivalent to proving that the system of equations from the original question has no rational solutions. So, I don't think your suggestions for proving that the degree of that extension is $9$ can avoid the system.

Comment: Oh I agree, I just wanted to offer some input about the degree of the extension. The only other thought I had was about using facts of the compositum, which would give that the extension was of degree at most 9, and divisible by 3 by the Tower Law, but you'd still have to argue why it couldn't be of degree 3 or 6, which boils down to the same things again.